# How can I format a Date in Java as only month, day and hour?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

How would I format the date, if I only need it to print the month (MMM), date (DD) and the hour (HH)?

So output would look something like:

```
Jul 18 9
```

(that being July 18th 09:00).

I've tried the following

```
private static void createDate () {

    String startConcat = startMonth + " " + startDate + " " + startTime;
    DateFormat start = new SimpleDateFormat ("MMM DD H");

    try {
       Date date = (Date)start.parse(startConcat);
       System.out.println(date);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }
}
```

Also it doesn't seem to read my month properly too...I am getting this as an output

```
Sun Jan 18 09:00:00 EST 1970
```

any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What are the values of startMonth, startDate and startTime?

Comment: @jim as shown above Jul = startMonth, 18 = startDate and 9 = startTime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `format` ([javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29)) method.

```
private static void createDate () throws Exception {
    String startConcat = startMonth + " " + startDate + " " + startTime;
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("MMM DD H");

    Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(startConcat);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
}
```

Comment: +1: If you only want specific fields in a specific format, you print those fields. You should only use the generic toString for Date if you want all field in a generic format.

Comment: thanks! that works, i see what i did wrong now, although theres still the problem of the month not accepting what startMonth is

Comment: What is the value of `startMonth`?

Comment: String startMonth, the input was Jul

Comment: the other two variables are ints

Comment: What output do you expect to get and what you actually are getting?

Comment: I expect to have `<month> <date> <time>` as my output, exactly what its giving at the moment, except it doesn't seem to format the month properly i.e. I am getting `Jan 18 9` instead of `Jul 18 9` as shown in my first post

Comment: nvm I figured it out, thanks for the help on the formatting though! (D = day in year, I was looking for d = day in month)

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the pattern for parsing the date, not printing the date. You will need to also use the pattern for the output;

```
System.out.println(start.format(date));
```